# Installation issue with safari

Tags: wine, package-management

I was trying to download and install `safari` on my desktop (Ubuntu 12.04). For that I used the below:

[How to Install Safari on Ubuntu](http://techhamlet.com/2011/02/safari-on-ubuntu/). Now after running the command as per above link : `sudo apt-get install wine` - I got the below:

```
pp@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.4 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
pp@ubuntu:~$
```

Could you tell me what do next? As I am very new user on Ubuntu, so confused.

Comment: have you tried installing wine through the software centre instead?

Comment: let me give it a try! Thanks for your caring to my pain.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, packages go broke. This can happen for several reasons, the most likely of which:

1. Somehow apt crashed or failed in an install process
2. Apt was running last time you shut down the computer
3. you told dpkg to force install something

in any case, this command usually fixes the problem:

```
user128825@askubuntu-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then try running the command to install wine.

If you can still install other packages, try to install the synaptic package manager. It can effectively diagnose problems like this one at startup, and even give you a list of broken packages.

Hope it helps!

--user128825

Edit: check the broken status category in Synaptic too. If you don't have it, find a way to install synaptic-package-manager. Try installing from there and you will get more details on what went wrong.